# Abrir Perfil do Facebook no aplicativo

Tags: html, android, facebook

Gostaria de saber como faço para abrir o aplicativo do facebook quando clicar no link. Nas pesquisas que fiz seria assim, mas não deu:

```
<a href="fb://profile/PerfilPessoa" />
```

mas isto abre apenas o aplicativo, não carrega o perfil da pessoa.

Comment: qual sistema não está funcionando iOS ou Android?

Comment: Estou testando no Android

Comment: Tente isto `facebook://facebook.com/wall?user={ID do usuário}`

Comment: o id do usuário entre chaves?

Comment: Não, as chaves era só pra ilustrar, deve ficar algo assim: `facebook://facebook.com/wall?user=10190190190`, só aceita numerico.

Comment: Não funcionou :\

Comment: Não funcionou como? De detalhes por favor

Comment: Agora consegui. Estava colocando o nome que vem depois do www.facebook.com/ em letras ao invés de por o id em numeros

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acredito que o perfil da pessoa tenha que ser o ID numerico e você deve estar adicionando o nome da pessoa

### Protocolo facebook://

```
facebook://facebook.com/inbox
facebook://facebook.com/info?user=544410940     (ID como "patrick.boos" não irá funcionar)
facebook://facebook.com/wall
facebook://facebook.com/wall?user=544410940   (isto irá funciona apenas se você tiver a pessoa adicionada a sua lista de amigos)
facebook://facebook.com/notifications
facebook://facebook.com/photos
facebook://facebook.com/album
facebook://facebook.com/photo
facebook://facebook.com/newsfeed
```

### Protocolo fb://

```
fb://root
fb://feed
fb://feed/{userID}
fb://profile
fb://profile/{userID}
fb://page/{id}
fb://group/{id}
fb://place/fw?pid={id}
fb://profile/{userID}/wall
fb://profile/{userID}/info
fb://profile/{userID}/photos
fb://profile/{userID}/mutualfriends
fb://profile/{userID}/friends
fb://profile/{userID}/fans
fb://search
fb://friends
fb://pages
fb://messaging
fb://messaging/{userID}
fb://online
fb://requests
fb://events
fb://places
fb://birthdays
fb://notes
fb://places
fb://groups
fb://notifications
fb://albums
```

> Estou procurando na documentação oficial os detalhes para formular os exemplos